# regular expression on date extract in hive

Tags: hive

Team,

Need help here.

I have column with value like "Sum total to percent on 02/27/2019" and I need to extract only date part of it from it and wherever column has value like above so I used below.

case when split(col1,' ')[0]='Sum' then substr(col1,-10) else null end as col2

but, problem is that I do have column values which starts with value like "Sum total and not necessary" so with above code I am getting result as  " necessary" which i do not need and should be replaced with null values.

my new column should get only date value and rest should be null. how this can achieved. kindly help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [regexp_extract](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) :

Demo:

```
Select regexp_extract(str,'\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}',0) as dt
from
(-- your data
select 'Sum total to percent on 02/27/2019' as str
)s
```

Result:

```
02/27/2019
```

Regular expression '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' means: two digits, slash two digits, slash, 4 digits

Comment: Here comes the savior :). I think I got it. I used below - regexp_replace(substr(col1,-10),"[^0-9/]+"," ")  and it returns all rows wherever the dates and rest all blank...